# Tensorflow throwing the FMA error while installing on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, tensorflow

I tried to install the Tensorflow CPU version by `pip install` on Ubuntu in a VirtualBox on Windows 10 host OS but after the installation, an error is thrown:

```
The TensorFlow library was compiled to use FMA instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
```

I found out that the FMA is a feature that comes with the AVX flag installed in the processor, so I suspected that maybe my CPU does not have such a feature.

However, after searching my processor on the intel website itself, I found out that it supports the AVX2 extension.

CPU specification

[image: img_specification]

My processor is Intel i5 9300H 2.40 GHz

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There's a 3 year old bug report on Virtual Box's website](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15471)  Unless Oracle decides to fix the problem, you won't be able to use TensorFlow (or anything else requiring the FMA instructions) in Virtual Box.

Since, when I encountered this problem, I was using Linux as my host operating system, I was able to use KVM/QEMU to solve my problem.  However, since you running Windows 10, that solution won't work for you.

In order to help you, I went to my Windows 10 Pro computer and started Hyper-V.  Inside Hyper-V I launched a virtual machine running Ubuntu 20.04.  Then I opened a terminal window and typed `cat /etc/cpuinfo` to verify that one of the supported CPU features is FMA.

While I can't guarantee that TensorFlow will work in Hyper-V, it looks like it will.  I believe you need Windows 10 Pro, not Home, in order to install Hyper-V.

P.S. According to [the CPU World website](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i5/Intel-Core%20i5%20i5-9300H.html) your processor supports FMA.

Comment: It's alright. I' m able to run it on miniconda  now. Thanks for the answer